# Synchronized FIFO Buffer Usage

Tags: java, buffer, synchronized, fifo

I am trying to create a system where one thread A adds items to a buffer, then another thread B is responsible for reading the items in the exact order they were entered, and then doing some potentially lengthily operations on them.

My best guess:

```
 Class B extends Thread {

    Buffer fifo = BufferUtils.synchronizedBuffer(new BoundedFifoBuffer());

    add(Object o) { // Thread A calls me, and doesn't deal well with delays :)
      fifo.add(o); // will the sync below prevent this from happening? 
                   // or can .add be independent of the sync ?
    }

    run() {
     synchronized (fifo) { // why am i sync'd here?  I am the only thread accessing...
         while ( item in buffer ) { // also how do i check this, and block otherwise?
            process(fifo.remove());
         }
     }
    |
  }
```

As you can see, I'm not even fully sure if synchronization is necessary.  The thread safety issue I have has nothing to do with the get() access, as there will only be one thread accessing it, but what is *most* important is that thread A calls .add() without any Concurrent Access Exception during thread B's processing of the buffer's contents.

Maybe I'm overthinking this?  Is it safe to being with? Your evaluation of this problem is much appreciated.

Sincerely,

Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you could also be interested in this [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) class.

Comment: Interested indeed, but my question remains:  can one thread add() to the queue while another remove()s from the queue without any concurrent access problems?

Comment: With a BlockingQueue the answer is yes, it is thread safe so you don't have to worry about synchronization.

You can read the docs http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html: "BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe..."

Comment: This is exacly what I need, thank you.   - LinkedBlockingQueue<E>

Comment: Thanks, I obviously didn't realize that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a stream of characters for logging the fastest approach may be to use a pipe.

```
    PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
    final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos, 256*1024);
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    es.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256*1024];
            int length;
            try {
                while ((length = pis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    // something slow.
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // time latency
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(pos);
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 10*1000*1000;
    for(int i=0;i<runs;i++) {
        pw.println("Hello "+i);
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took an average of %,d nano-seconds per line%n", time/runs);
    es.shutdown();
```

prints

```
    Took an average of 269 nano-seconds per line
```

Note: the pipe itself doesn't create any garbage. (Unlike a queue)

---

You can use ExecutorService to wrap up a queue and thread(s)

```
ExecutorService es =

es.submit(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     process(o);
  }
});
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this wouldn't be appropriate in my case because there are millions of items in the queue, and i need just one worker thread to process them all.

Comment: Not sure why you would want millions of items to be queued up.  That sounds rather inefficient, but it doesn't make any difference.  You can have millions of tasks and a single threaded pool.

Comment: The worker thread is meant for logging character output.  The main thread needs to indicate that the character needs to be logged, then move on to it's more pressing work.    The worker thread then needs to  read characters from the buffer and write them to a file, taking it's time if necessary.  So to answer your question, my queue is a queue of characters.